# Product prices in ProductCockpit

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

For some products I need to change the price in ProductCockpit. If I change the price in ProductCockpit Staged Version the change is directly displayed on site,without doing synchronizing from Staged to Online Catalog.What can I do to make it available for Staged first and then after doing synchronization to Online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PriceRows offer 2 methods to identify a product.

1. Reference to a specific product in a specific CatalogVersion using the attribute "product" of type Product. This will match a product in a single CatalogVersion (e.g. "Staged").
2. Identify a product by its code using the attribute "productId" of type String. This will match a product in all CatalogVersions (e.g. "Staged" and "Online").

Check which one you are using and change to the reference version, if you would like to change prices only for a specific version.

Comment: Will making PriceRow catalog aware item type solve the problem ?

Comment: I don't think you need to make changes to PriceRow. Just use attribute "product" instead of "productId". Didn't that work for you?